# C# - Using Black Scholes Newton returns NaN occasionally

Tags: options, black-scholes, programming

First caveat:  I'm a programmer doing this for a client, and my knowledge of options probably has holes in it.  So be a little forgiving here.  =)

The Issue:  When I run Black Scholes Newton against all options in a chain, I occasionally get NaN return values.  My comparison for accuracy is against ThinkorSwim's numbers.

Here are screencaps of the issue:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0vYN.jpg

spot, strike, time, etc, are all there.  And most of the time the numbers are accurate.  But once I hit certain ranges with Calls and Puts, I get those NaN's, and I can't seem to figure out the pattern as to *why*

I'm using garagebandhedgefund's code as a base, with adjustments for puts/calls.

Here's the Newton Code:

```
 public static double OptionPriceImpliedVolatilityCallBlackScholesNewton(double S, double K, double r, double time, double optionPrice,bool iscall, bool isput,out double price,out double diff)
    {
        price = 0;
        diff = 0;
        int MAX_ITERATIONS = 100;
        double ACCURACY = 1.0e-5;
        double t_sqrt = Math.Sqrt(time);
        double sigma = (optionPrice / S) / (0.398 * t_sqrt);    // find initial value  
         price = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ITERATIONS; i++)
        {
            if (iscall)
            {
                 price = OptionPriceCallBlackScholes(S, K, r, sigma, time);
            }
            if (isput)
            {
                 price = OptionPricePutBlackScholes(S, K, r, sigma, time);
            }
            diff = optionPrice - price;
            if (Math.Abs(diff) < ACCURACY)
                return sigma;
            double d1 = (Math.Log(S / K) + r * time) / (sigma * t_sqrt) + 0.5 * sigma * t_sqrt;
            double vega = (S * t_sqrt * NormDist(d1));
            sigma = sigma + diff / vega;
        }
        return sigma;  // something screwy happened, should throw exception  // <--- original code  
        //throw new Exception("An error occurred"); // Comment this line if you uncomment the line above  
    }
```

My question:  Is it my code?  Is it certain ranges of values?  Are there cases where Newton fails to return valid values?  I'm kinda stumped here.

For the record, when I use this data against garageband's Bisection code, I get errors across the board.  I don't know if that's related.  I'm fairly certain of the accuracy of my input data, since I do get *some* valid returns with Newton.

Comment: garagebandhedgefund seems to be down now, does anyone have the code base saved? https://web.archive.org/web/20150212044848/http://www.garagebandhedgefund.com/formulas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some option prices can't be converted to volatility. E.g. A bid for an in-the-money call which is below its intrinsic value. So sometimes NaN is a valid answer.
Best way to handle it is to do precursory checks before going down to the search loop.

Answer (score 1):

.NET doubles return `double.NaN` when you do things like divide zero by zero. With doubles, anything less than `double.Epsilon` is "zero" for the purpose of this result.

I suggest that your `vega` is less than `double.Epsilon`

What happens if you run the same method using `decimal` instead?

Comment: I converted everything to decimal, but just wound up with either 'divide by zero' or 'number too large/small for decimal'  So the problem *is* with the Vega being generated.  As a band-aid, I set minimum/maximum range checking.